# Getting birth certificate of Augusta Fluger Pasch born in Hamburg in 1834?

Tags: germany, birth-records, 1830s

I would like to have a birth certificate of Augusta born in Hamburg - Germany in 1834. His father was Clemens Augustus Fluegels and his mother Magdalena Pasch.

When she was born, her father was 22 years old. She was the oldest of four brothers. she married with Miguel Ely Braum on January 17, 1857 in Caracas. she had eight children. She died in Caracas on January 23, 1912 at age 78.

Answer (score 2):

The birth is likely documented in the *Zivilstandsregister*, which are available for the period between 1811 and 1875 at the [Hamburg state archive](https://www.hamburg.de/bkm/familienforschung/4307636/tipps-fuer-die-familienforschung). Another source might be church records, available from the same archive or local parishes (you have to determine the parish first).